# Failing miserably with .htaccess rewrite, unsure how to troubleshoot

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

I have been trying to figure out URL rewriting on my local development site all day with no luck. Initially the .htaccess files were ignored. Now they are being read but not working. I don't know how to troubleshoot an .htaccess file though. From what I have read, it seems Apache 2.4 got rid of specifying your own RewriteLog. The only help I am getting is from /var/log/apache2/error.log which is all Greek to me.

The rewrite I am attempting is simply:
local.domain.com/users/index.php?id=1  ->  local.domain.com/users/1/

My .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)/?$ users/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

When requesting local.domain.com/users/index.php?id=1 , the URL remains unchanged. The error.log for apache gives the following 3 lines:

```
[Tue Jun 17 15:20:04.705939 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6569] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:46208] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.domain.com/sid#b63f02c0][rid#b6b12058/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/users/index.php -> users/index.php
[Tue Jun 17 15:20:04.705979 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6569] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:46208] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.domain.com/sid#b63f02c0][rid#b6b12058/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/] applying pattern '^users/([0-9]+)$' to uri 'users/index.php'
[Tue Jun 17 15:20:04.705990 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 6569] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:46208] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.domain.com/sid#b63f02c0][rid#b6b12058/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/] pass through /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/users/index.php
```

The location of the .htaccess is /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/ . Is there a way to get better/more log info? Is the /var/log/apache2/error.log really the log I should be using for this? Is the problem really with my .htaccess code or is there some sort of configuration I am missing or something? I know there are similar questions but so far I haven't found one that was both understandable and a solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error are you getting and what is location of your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rewriting an *incoming* URI `/users/1/` *to* `/users/index.php?id=1` (SEO form to dynamic form). Your .htaccess looks correct for that (I assume it's in the root).

Are you sure that your Apache server is built with the RewriteEngine enabled? Are you overlooking an error message? Your typed-in URI is `/users/1/`?

Comment: Strange. I know I had tried /users/1/ and it hadn't worked. Apparently I changed something since then though. I had been typing both the query string form and the prettier form because I wasn't sure exactly what would happen. Thanks both of you though it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You regex is looking for `[0+9]+` which means it is looking for numbers after `/users`.  In your input url (assuming that's your input url), `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/users/index.php` there is no numbers after `'/users'

Put a number after users like `/users/55555/` and see what happens.